# How to use DynamicComponentLoader in Angular2?

Tags: angular

In Angular2 RC version, I can use `DynamicComponentLoader`, but Angular release version document removed `DynamicComponentLoader` API. Is there a substitute?

Comment: `DynamicComponentLoader` is gone quite some time already. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36325212/angular-2-dynamic-tabs-with-user-click-chosen-components/36325468#36325468 for an example of the new API.